# angular js use checked() instead of indexof() for a checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a javascript like this to check if a checkbox is checked:

```
$scope.toggleCheck = function (course) {
    //checkedfunction(course);
    if (($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course) === -1)) {
        $scope.selectedCourses.push(course);
        $scope.planned += 3;    
    } else {
        $scope.selectedCourses.splice($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course), 1);
        $scope.planned -= 3;
    }
    $scope.getPercentage();
};
```

and in the html i have:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkedfunction(child)" ng-click="toggleCheck(child)" ng-disabled="required == (planned+completed) && (selectedCourses.indexOf(child) == -1) | filter: checkMpttdetails(child)" value=""/>
```

I would like to know if there is any `checked()` function to check if the check box is checked instead of using the `indexof()` property?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery (not jqLite - although it might work), then pass 'this' to your click handler:

```
ng-click="toggleCheck(this, child)"
```

and in your click handler:

```
$scope.toggleCheck = function(element, course){
     if ($(element).is(':checked)) {
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="required == (planned+completed) && (selectedCourses.indexOf(child) == -1) | filter: checkMpttdetails(child)" ng-checked="isChecked" />
```

You can check/uncheck the checkbox by toggling `$scope.isChecked` - also, you can check if it is checked by checking the value of `$scope.isChecked`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$event`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) object to get access to the element being actioned on an ng-click. Within this object is a property called `target` which (for a checkbox input) has a `checked` state.

```
ng-click="toggleCheck($event)"
```

controller function:

```
$scope.toggleCheck = function($event){
    var thisCheckbox = $event.target;
    if (thisCheckbox.checked) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is pure Angular and does not require any additional libraries.